# Web extension for firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm making a webextension for firefox and the only problem I'm having currently is that there are no vertical scrollbars. I am using 'panel' as the type on chrome.windows.create with a height and width of 880px.

I've tried using the

```
body{
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

But that hasn't added a scrollbar for me. Any suggestions, and if i need to show code for specifics I will I just do not know where to start.

Comment: try to adding also `overflow-x:hidden;` may be it fix your problem.

Comment: Nah, it didn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: I update it from none to hidden you check it too? I had same problem before and I found in firefox you have to add both overflow-x and y

Comment: Tried that as well to no avail.

Comment: as @mfvjunior said did you add height?

Comment: I did, but the fix for me was html,body{} with your suggestion of the hidden on overflow-x.

Comment: yes so it fixed finally , good, write your own answer, it can help other with same problem

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll close the question in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @mfvjunior and @mkafiyan I came up with my solution.

```
html, body{
overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; height:800px;
}
```

I don't truly understand the reason it is the answer compared to just adding the code from the brackets to body only, but I hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: Since the major issue is giving it a height, I suggest you accept _mfvjunior_ answer instead of posting your own. For an answer to be accepted, it must not have _full_ coverage of all angles of a question.

Comment: unfortunately tho, the given answer of body{code} did not work. It had to be with the html.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the height property for body css rule.

```
body{
overflow-y:scroll;
height: '800px';
}
```

Comment: That was close and it helped me find my answer. What i did was

Comment: html, body{
 
 overflow-y:scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 height:800px;
 
}